# Find a value of Key in Json Array - Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a Json array which has key value pairs. I want to get value of a particular key in the list. I don't know at what position the key will be in the array so I cant use the index in the array.

How can I get this please? I have tried something like below code to get value of 'filterB' which is 'val1' but no luck. Thanks.

```
import json
x = '{"filters":[{"filterA":"All"},{"filterB":"val1"}]}'
y = json.loads(x)
w = y['filters']['filterB']
print (w)
```

Comment: How would you do it if the data *didn't* come from JSON?

Comment: I would have to iterate it through the list. I wanted to see if it is possible to get the values of Jarray based on key without iterating the whole array list.

Comment: It's just a list, nothing to do with an "array"; and the way you do it when the data comes from JSON is the same way - because the data that you have is *identical to what you'd get* if there were no JSON involved. That's the *point* of the `json` library: to convert JSON documents into *ordinary* Python data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w = y['filters']['filterB']` doesn't work because `y['filters']` is a `list` and not `dict`.

The answer to your question depends on how you want to handle the case of multiple dictionaries inside `filters` list that have `filterB` key.

```
import json
x = '{"filters":[{"filterA":"All"},{"filterB":"val1"}]}'
y = json.loads(x)

# all filterB values
filter_b_values = [x['filterB'] for x in y['filters'] if 'filterB' in x.keys()] 

# take first filterB value or None if no values
w = filter_b_values[0] if filter_b_values else None
```

Comment: You don't need to check `'filterB' in x.keys()`. `'filterB' in x` does the same thing

Comment: @gabip This is a simpler version that I was expecting to implement. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your data (json) has nothing to do with what you want, which is to find the dictionary in `y['filters']` that contains a key called `filterB`. To do this, you need to iterate over the list and look for the item that fulfils this condition.

```
w = None
for item in y['filters']:
    if 'filterB' in item:
        w = item['filterB']
        break

print(w) # val1
```

Alternatively, you could join all dictionaries into a single dictionary and use that like you originally tried

```
all_dict = dict()
for item in y['filters']:
    all_dict.update(item)

# Replace the list of dicts with the dict
y['filters'] = all_dict

w = y['filters']['filterB']
print(w) # val1
```

If you have multiple dictionaries in the list that fulfil this condition and you want `w` to be a list of all these values, you could do:

```
y = {"filters":[{"filterA":"All"},{"filterB":"val1"},{"filterB":"val2"}]}
all_w = list()
for item in y['filters']:
    if 'filterB' in item:
        all_w.append(item['filterB'])
```

Or, as a list-comprehension:

```
all_w = [item['filterB'] for item in y['filters'] if 'filterB' in item]
print(all_w) # ['val1', 'val2']
```

Note that a list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for an iteration that creates a list. You aren't avoiding any looping by writing a regular loop as a list comprehension

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to achieve this without iteration? I tried something like below but it is not working.
l =['filterB']
z = [w[x] for x in l if x in w]
print(z)

Comment: @Muthu No. Since you have a list, you must iterate over each item. Even if you use a different function or a list comprehension, there is iteration hidden at some level